# Is Cantor Set measurable with Riemann Theory?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm studying Functional Analysis and Lebesgue Measure.

I know that the standard Cantor Set $C$ is compact because is bounded by $[0,1]$ and it's closed because is an intersection of closed sets. Moreover:

$$\mathcal{L}(C)=\mathcal{L}(\bigcap\limits_{0}^{\infty} C_k)=\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \mathcal{L}(C_k)=\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}\frac{2^k}{3^k}=0$$

So $C$ is Lebesgue Measurable with measure 0.

I'm struggling because if it's compact I think it's Riemann measurable too, isn't it? What's its Riemann Measure? Or maybe it can't be defined on this set?

Comment: What does "Riemann measurable" mean?

Comment: I don't know if it is a proper term. I mean the measurable sets that can be measured with rectangulars, rectangular prisms in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or other strange volumes in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: So basically you're asking if the indicator function of the Cantor set is Riemann-integrable, correct ?

Comment: What do you mean with indicator function of the Cantor set?

Comment: I think @Matrefeytontias's description is the closest to the original question. The indicator (characteristic) function of Cantor set is Riemann integrable; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864206/characteristic-function-of-cantor-set-is-riemann-integrable. It takes a little while to mint a proof for this.

Comment: If you're thinking of rectangular bounding regions you may be thinking of Jordan Measure which is a weaker but more historically motivated measure than the lebesgue measure.